# LogicException: The selected node does not have a form ancestor. error with symfony2 phpunit testing

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit

I always get the following error when I try to fill out a form with PHPUnit Functional Testing: `LogicException: The selected node does not have a form ancestor. error with symfony2 phpunit testing`

Here is the code, the error shows up at the last line of code:

```
        $editusercrawler = $client->request('GET', '/profile');
    $this->assertTrue($editusercrawler->filter('html:contains("Edit Profile")')->count() > 0);


    // Go To Edit
    $link = $editusercrawler->filter('a:contains("Edit Profile")')->eq(0)->link();
    $editusercrawler = $client->click($link);
    //var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());

    // Check if User Edit was called
    $this->assertTrue($editusercrawler->filter('html:contains("Edit User")')->count() > 0);
    //var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());
    // Fill out form

    //var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());
    $editusercrawler = $client->click($link);
    $editusercrawler = $client->request('GET', '/profile/edit');
    var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());

    $editUserForm = $editusercrawler->selectButton('update')->form();
```

Comment: So the problem is that there is a form but the crawler is not able to see it?

Comment: I think so, even though I can see it by printing the content of the client: var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem appears, when HTML isn't structured properly. 
The setNode method has the following structure (I am using Laravel )

```
protected function setNode(\DOMElement $node)
{
    $this->button = $node;
    if ('button' === $node->nodeName || ('input' === $node->nodeName && in_array(strtolower($node->getAttribute('type')), array('submit', 'button', 'image')))) {
        if ($node->hasAttribute('form')) {
            // if the node has the HTML5-compliant 'form' attribute, use it
            $formId = $node->getAttribute('form');
            $form = $node->ownerDocument->getElementById($formId);
            if (null === $form) {
                throw new \LogicException(sprintf('The selected node has an invalid form attribute (%s).', $formId));
            }
            $this->node = $form;
        return;
    }
    // we loop until we find a form ancestor
    do {
        if (null === $node = $node->parentNode) {
            throw new \LogicException('The selected node does not have a form ancestor.');
        }
    } while ('form' !== $node->nodeName);
} elseif ('form' !== $node->nodeName) {
    throw new \LogicException(sprintf('Unable to submit on a "%s" tag.', $node->nodeName));
}

$this->node = $node;
```

}

- As you see, the method first checks if node name matches
  button/input, while going further for input tag by verifying the
  'type' attribute.
- Next it checks for the form attribute. Otherwise it throws exception.
  Now $this->node is set.
- Here comes the final explanation
  Currently you have $node (you can use dd() or var_dump() to see output) set, as next parentNode will be checked. With a do while loop it searches so long, until the nodeName wont be named "form".

As said in the beginning, your HTML isn't structured properly.

**INVALID EXAMPLE**

```
<form>
<div id="first">
<input type="text" value="Wont check this">
<div/>
</form>
<div id="second">
<input type="submit" value="Working">
</div>
```

**VALID EXAMPLE**

```
<form>
<div id="first">
<input type="text" value="Wont check this">
<div/>
<div id="second">
<input type="submit" value="Working">
</div>
</form>
```

Thats a simple explanation why it wont work. In my case, I was starting form inside the bootstrap panel-body div, but had submit button in panel-footer div.